# Receive an ftp file in my asp.net web site

Tags: asp.net, post, ftp

I've got a windows based application (not one I have control over) that will push an xml file to an ftp server.  I would like to have that file automatically processed by my asp.net application without having to poll the ftp server.  From within the windows application I can control the ftp server that it is being sent to, so I could setup an ftp server on my iis box, but then i would still have to poll for a change in the file.  I am open to any suggestions on accomplishing this without having to poll an ftp server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FileSystemWatcher class is designed to monitor a directory and respond to events such as the creation of a file.

I'd suggest creating a Windows Service application to host the FileSystemWatcher and handle the OnCreated event.

FileSystemWatcher:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

OnCreated event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.oncreated%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Links in the markdown appear to be misbehaving... sorry for the malformed post.

Comment: Thanks Rick, this makes sense.  I have used the FileSystemWatcher class in the past, but didn't think of using it in this context.  I'm pretty sure I can get this done, but before I head down that road does anyone know if I'm reinventing the wheel here.  I've gotta think others have had a need like this before.  Are there existing solutions?  I guess my ideal scenario would be to take an ftp put and convert it to an http post (which is probably how I would implement it).

Comment: @TomLynch One thing which you may need to watch out for with this approach is waiting until the file has finished uploading before you being processing, as the OnCreated method may fire as soon as the upload begins but before it has completed. You may be able to check the LastModified date and only do your processing after X minutes have elapsed to ensure that no more data is being written.

Comment: Good point, Mun. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Interesting this got closed for being too vague when Rick's response was right on point within minutes of the post.  I would still like to find an existing solution to this problem rather than coding it up myself, but thanks for the direction on this Rick.

Comment: @Mun Thanks for pointing out the potential gotcha